# WCF Seralization issue with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

I am getting this weird exception in WCF Service `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`

Here is the given schema of the DB:
[image: DB Schema]

Here is how it's created in DB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [appUser] (
  [use_id] int PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1,1),
  [firstName] nvarchar(150),
  [lastName] nvarchar(150),
  [gender] nvarchar(10) DEFAULT 'M',
  [phoneNo] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
  [image] nvarchar(max) DEFAULT 'abcdlkfs',
  [userType] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  [smsConfirmationCode] nvarchar(10),
  [smsVerifed] nvarchar DEFAULT '0',
  [createdOn] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),                
);


CREATE TABLE [parent] (
  [par_id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  [use_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [appUser](use_id),
  [CNIC] nvarchar(150),
);


CREATE TABLE [student] (
  [stu_id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  [use_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [appUser](use_id),
  [par_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [parent](par_id),
  [regNo] nvarchar(150),
  [section] nvarchar(1) DEFAULT 'A',
  [discipline] nvarchar(150),
  [semesterNo] int DEFAULT 1,
  [isFreeze] bit DEFAULT 0,
  [admmisionDate] datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  [semesterUpdateDate] datetime,
);


CREATE TABLE [teacher] (
  [tea_id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  [use_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [appUser](use_id),
  [empNo] nvarchar(150),
);


CREATE TABLE [message] (
  [msg_id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  [from] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [appUser](use_id),
  [to] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [appUser](use_id),
  [body] nvarchar(max),
  [sentOn] datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  [deliveredOn] datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  [status] nvarchar(30) DEFAULT 'pending',
);
```

Now after adding Entity Framework 6.x into the WCF Project it starts to give get ugly , Here is what happens:

[image: EF 6.x]

IF the record is empty it returns empty array `[]` that's fine, but when there is some record it just throw around the **Runtime.Serialization Exception** and resets the connections with client. *(The exception message can only be seen in Output window of Visual Studio)*

IF I debug that even the data is coming back fine:
[image: Debug Window pic]

But after I continue the process this happens in Visual Studio:
[image: Output Window of VS]

This is what we see at the POSTMAN:
[image: Postman Output]

**EDIT:** After more analysis: this is what the error message is:

> Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.appUser_CB3ECC520FC14134E25C71D649FF5FCD8A0830D35A865C6798E272A4515435E1' with data contract name 'appUser_CB3ECC520FC14134E25C71D649FF5FCD8A0830D35A865C6798E272A4515435E1:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

Comment: It seems to me that there is something wrong with the process of serialization and deserialization. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types

Comment: @AbrahamQian I have already cross checked all datatypes, they are fine